# Securing Apache on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, security

What tips do you have to secure Apache(2.2) on Windows?

Comment: Depends what you're serving with it.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the Center for Internet Security benchmark for securing Apache.

http://www.cisecurity.org/bench_apache.html

Josh